# Is there a way to put the data in front of a label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, background, plot-annotations

It seems that the labels in Matplotlib always are shown on the most top overlay, covering the data behind it.

Example:

[image]

The plot has 2 text annotations in red.
The bottom one is overlayed by a gray "Meteo" text.

Is there a way to move the red annotation above the gray text label?

I was playing with the [`zorder`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this only works with [annotations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html) but not with [text](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

Below an example:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# foreground annotation
a1 = ax.annotate("annotation", (0.5, 0.5), fontsize='xx-large', color="red", zorder=9)
a1.set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=5, foreground='white'), path_effects.Normal()])

# background annotation
a2 = ax.annotate("Another annotation", (0.6, 0.48), fontsize='xx-large', color="blue", zorder=5)
a2.set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=5, foreground='white'), path_effects.Normal()])

# zorder ignored:
t1 = fig.text(0.56, 0.49, "Background", color='gray', ha='right', zorder=0)
t1.set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=3, foreground='white'), path_effects.Normal()])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It works properly, but not in a way You might expect.

Every element has it's `zorder`. Even `ax` has default `zorder=0`. It means, that all elements within that, let's call it a **layer**, will have final `zorder=0`.

But when `ax` *layer* is drawn, `zorder` is applied to every element respectively and are placed correctly in the view from bottom to the top.
So now You have `ax` **layer** rendered with final `zorder=0`.

Then You are adding text with `fig.text`. Which adds text to the figure **layer**. So now You have two objects to render; `ax` **layer** with `zorder = 0` and `text` with `zorder=0` as well. You can set text `zorder=-1` which will put text below `ax` **layer**, but it will be invisible if `ax` has solid background. Try to add another `text` in the `fig` **layer** with higher or lower `zorder` and it will be properly drawn on top or below another `text` element.